# pyhooks input text field detection

Tags: python, text, input, detect

I am writing a python program that assist with pasting addresses into an external program. Basically, the user copies an adress from Google maps- the program isolates the street number, street name, city and state. The user would then open the external program and simply "click to paste". The program would simply paste the next item in the list into the next input field the user clicked into. So the user would need to click in a specific order.

What is the best way to detect when a user clicks into a input text field in a NONPYTHON application, that has nothing to do with my script. I just want the python script to detect when a user clicks in a input field area, and then fire my currently existing paste function. (I have everything working except detecting the input field.) I am using the win32lib, pyhooks and ctypes.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcom to Stack Overflow. Please ask a specific question about some code you have written. Asking about "the best way" is generally not a good idea.

Comment: My apologies. I will post the code soon. On a different computer right now. Thanks.